# Different notification partials for different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

**notifications/index** has `<%= render partial: "notifications/notification", collection: @notifications %>`, which contains:

```
<%= link_to "", notifications_habit_path(notification.id), method: :delete, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %> 
<%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.name, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> 
commented on <%= link_to "your habit", habit_path(notification) %>
```

which shows:

[image]

This is problematic because it should say 3x *".com commented on your habit"* and 2x *".com commented on your value"*.

We need to create two separate partials **notifications/_habits** & **notifications/_values**.

My confusion is how to make the code know when to direct to the habit partial or the value partial based on whether it's a habit or value.

**notifications_controller**

```
def index
  @habits = current_user.habits
  @valuations = current_user.valuations #aka values
  @notifications = current_user.notifications
  @notifications.each do |notification|
    notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
end
```

The notifications are based on if a user comments on one of your habits or values:

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true

private

  def create_notification
      Notification.create(
       user_id: self.user_id,
       comment_id: self.id,
       read: false
      )
  end
end
```

I followed this tutorial but it is based on using just one model: http://evanamccullough.com/2014/11/ruby-on-rails-simple-notifications-system-tutorial/

### UPDATE FOR VALADAN

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def index
        @comments = @commentable.comments
    end

    def new
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
            redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to @commentable, notice: "comment destroyed."
    end

  def like
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_like = current_user.comment_likes.build(comment: @comment)
    if @comment_like.save
            @comment.increment!(:likes)
        flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
      end  
        redirect_to(:back)
  end

private

  def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

    def load_commentable
        resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
        @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
    end

    def comment_params
        params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commentable, :user_id, :like)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed

```
<% if notification.habit_id %>
        <%= link_to "your habit", habit_path(notification) %>
<% elsif notification.valuation_id %>
        <%= link_to "your value", valuation_path(notification) %>
<% elsif notification.quantified_id %>
        <%= link_to "your stat", quantified_path(notification) %>
<% elsif notification.goal_id %>
        <%= link_to "your goal", goal_path(notification) %>
<% end %>
```

and in the comment model:

```
  def create_notification
    Notification.create(
     habit_id: self.habit_id,
     valuation_id: self.valuation_id,
     quantified_id: self.quantified_id,
     goal_id: self.goal_id,
     user_id: self.user_id,
     comment_id: self.id,
     read: false
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your notification is associated with comment, and comment can have commentable of type Habit or Value  (you havent show those two model, so lets call them Habit and Value models).
So you can check if notification is for Habit or Value by checking commentable type like this:

```
Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).commentable.class == Habit
```

or check if its value notification:

```
Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).commentable.class == Value
```

Similar way is checking polymorphic type on the comment, like:

```
Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).commentable_type == 'Habit'
```

So on the end, you dont actualy need two partials just IF and two different link_to, one for value and one for habit.

```
<%= link_to "", notifications_habit_path(notification.id), method: :delete, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %>
<%= link_to Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.name, user_path(Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).user.id) %> commented on 
<% if Comment.find_by(notification.comment_id).commentable.class == Habit %>
<%= link_to "your habit", habit_path(notification) %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "your value", value_path(notification) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much Vladan! All your lines of code, but no matter what follows the `if` they still all show "your habit". And your definitely right your method is better than different partials. I added the comments controller maybe the issue lies there?

Comment: I think `if` it sees there is just one Habit than it shows all "your habit" for every instance `else`  if it doesn't see any Habit it will show all "your value"